With Python, how do I render the current frame to a file without changing the current render settings?
I'm using Blender as a video editor, and have my render settings
configured the way I want for the video output.  While editing, I often
want to render the current frame to a separate PNG file (for
freeze-frame insets, for example).  Currently, I do this using Render ->
Render Image (F12), then in the new window, Image -> Save As (Shift Alt
S), then pick a file name, etc.  As this menuing process is tedious, I
would like to write a Python script to render the current frame to a
file in one step.
I have found several existing answers that describe how to do this
(example), but they
generally work by destructively changing context.scene.render and I
want to avoid that.  In my case, I need to set both file name and
the output format.
The seemingly obvious approach is to save the original file name and
format, change them, render, then restore them.  However, I see in the
GUI that changing the output format (e.g., from "FFMPEG" to "PNG") also
changes what other options are available, and I am concerned that simply
setting and then restoring this format might have other side effects.
For example, if Blender forgets all of the FFMPEG settings when the
format is changed to PNG, then when it is changed back, some things
would be restored to their defaults, which would be very bad since this
operation is supposed to be non-destructive.
In another answer,
they create a fresh scene object, which would avoid altering the current
scene, but I'm concerned that the new scene might not inherit the
current scene's render settings.  I want the created image file to be as
similar to the corresponding frame of the final animation as possible (I
realize that the compression artifacts will necessarily be different),
and hence for the current scene's render settings to be used to the
extent applicable.
This is what I currently have:
import bpy
import os

def main(context):
    # Get the output directory of the main output file.
    dir = os.path.dirname(context.scene.render.filepath)

    # Name the new file according to the current frame number.
    frame_num = context.scene.frame_current
    new_filepath = os.path.join(dir, f"frame-{frame_num}.png")
    print(new_filepath)

    # Save the current render settings so we can restore them at the end.
    orig_filepath = context.scene.render.filepath
    orig_file_format = context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format

    try:
        # Modify the settings to write a single image file.
        context.scene.render.filepath = new_filepath
        context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"

        # Render the image.
        print("Rendering...")
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        print("Done!")

    finally:
        try:
            # Try to restore the scene render settings.
            context.scene.render.filepath = orig_filepath
            context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = orig_file_format
        except Exception as e:
            # Log, but swallow so whatever the original exception was
            # can propagate and be seen in the UI.
            print(f"Exn while restoring values: {e}")

The above seems to work, but it seems unclean and potentially dangerous
to set and restore like this.
What is the proper way to do this?

Don't worry, your script looks fine. The alternatives would be worse. Changing a value won't reset related properties.

As the primary concern with the script in the question is that changing the output format to something else and then changing it back might have side effects, I performed a simple test:

Change render.ffmpeg.gopsize to 10 from its default of 18.
Change render.image_settings.file_format to PNG and back.
Observe that render.ffmpeg.gopsize is still 10.

For step 2, I made the change both manually in the UI and via the script in the question.
That experiment is summarized in this screenshot:

From this experiment, a few days of successful usage, and a comment on the question, I conclude that setting and restoring the file_format is in fact the best way to do this, despite its inelegance.
